# MathJax and LaTeX \definecolor

Tags: colors, latex, mathjax

It seems that `\definecolor` doesn't work in Mathjax for me.

I use MathJax 2.0 and I included TeX: {extension: "color.js"}.

For example, TEX code

```
$$\definecolor{somecolor}{RGB}{1243,45,46} \color{somecolor}{test}$$
```

is rendered in MathJax as

> \definecolorsomecolorRGB123,45,46test

and `\definecolor` is show in red.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here on StackOverflow, you might want to try your luck at [tex.se].

Comment: From what I have seen, TeX.SE is not open to MathJax related questions at all.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger We are happy to take questions where the answer will not be tied to the MathJax 'back end' (which is not a TeX implementation: just an interpretor of a subset of the TeX math notation). Here, the question is about what MathJax understands, which really is not something TeX expertise helps with.

Comment: @JosephWright yes, didn't mean to make my comment sound as negative as it is (on second reading). I think this is a good example for an "edge" question where the OP can't know where which is the right SE-site to post it. What I wanted to prevent was that this gets sent to TeX.SE.  Evidently I failed at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `extensions` not `extension`.  The red `\definecolor` indicates that the macro isn't defined, so that should point you to check whether the extension has been loaded correctly.  In this case, the spelling of the property means that MathJax will not see the request to load the extension, and so it isn't loaded, and so `\definecolor` is never defined.

On the other hand, even if you get it to load properly, you will find that the current version of `color.js` doesn't implement the `RGB` color space, only the `rgb` one (this is fixed in the upcoming v2.1 of MathJax).  So you should convert to decimals between 0 and 1 (using 123/256, 45/256 and 36/256).  That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I correctly wrote extensions in my code. I wrote it here incorrectly. And I switched to rgb, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link to an actual page the displays the issue?  It would probably be easier and faster for me to see what is happening than to guess and have you check.  If not, can you post the complete configuration (including the `script` tag) that you are using?  In the meantime, can you type `javascript:alert(MathJax.Message.Log())`  in the URL area and see if the color.js file is actually being loaded?

Comment: Thank you. Issue is resolved.